# Cannot enter if statement

Tags: if-statement

As a part of a larger script following if statement:

```
    Logger.log(vr5);
    if (vr5 == "zwak met 5-4 krt in ♡/♠"){     
    Logger.log("in if");
    }
```

Logger gives:  vr5: zwak met 5-4 krt in ♡/♠
But is does not enter the if Logger. "in if" does not show up
Second exampel.

```
    Logger.log(vr7);
    if (vr7 == "3♣ (6 krt ♡ en 5-7 p), 3♢ (6 krt ♠ en 5-7 p), 3♡ (6 krt ♠ en 
    8-10 p), 3♠ (6 krt ♡ en 8-10 p)"){
    Logger.log("in if");
    }
```

Also in this case Logger vr7: 3♣ (6 krt ♡ en 5-7 p), 3♢ (6 krt ♠ en 5-7 p), 3♡ (6 krt ♠ en 8-10 p), 3♠ (6 krt ♡ en 8-10 p) full fills the if condition, but does not enter the if.

What i am doing wrong? Who can help me?

PS vr5 and vr7 are answers in a googleform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: In which language?

Comment: Ths zie my comment on that (compareTo has to replace by equals and then it works....

Answer (score 0):

I read all the possibility of "How do I compare strings in Java" but none of them worked. The answer of Mohammed E. ManSour was (nr.3):

```
if (string1.compareTo(string2) == 0)
{
// this line WILL print
System.out.println("The two strings are the same.")
}
```

However google apps script does not recognize compareTo. So instead of compareTo I tried string1.equals(string2) == 0). See my first example.

```
if (vr5.equals("zwak met 5-4 krt in ♡/♠") == 0){
Logger.log("in if");
}
```

This works!